# continuations as meaningful comprehensions

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations

Monads may be construed as forms of containers:

- list : aggregation of items from a given type
- bag  : unordered aggregation
- set  : unordered aggregation that ignores multiplicity
- Maybe : aggregation of at-most one item
- Reader e : aggregations of cardinality |e|

I am wondering how continuations are interpreted in this view as forms of packages / containers, in a meaningful fashion. Thanks!

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Continuation

Comment: The right way to continue with this intuition may be to abandon it: not all monads are containers (or at least not very elegantly).  `State`, `Writer`, and – yes – `Cont`, for instance, doesn't feel like containers at all.  "Container" is an intuition that might help you get your foot in the door, but it's something you'll need to generalize.  (Incidentally, "container" to me feels like a more useful intuition for functors – but again, not perfect by any means.)

Comment: @AntalS-Z Is there another intuition that you'd recommend?

Comment: Why are you looking for "intuition" rather than understanding? If monads were intuitive, you'd understand them already, without asking any questions! Monads as containers is more like an analogy: one that works well for List and Maybe, kinda works for IO, and is rather stretched for most of the others.

Comment: If you are looking for a very quick and dirty intuition, I'd look at monads as "programmable semicolons" (as in redefining the `;` in `a;b`) rather than containers.

Comment: @Moses: The only monad tutorial I ever recommend is [“You Could Have Invented Monads!  (And Maybe You Already Have.)”](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html), by Dan “sigfpe” Piponi.  It isn’t so much about intuition as about *why* we want monads: monads are what allow us to compose functions that do something *other* than just produce a result.  (But really, that’s a pale one-sentence summary – the whole post is worth reading.)

Comment: @amalloy what is the type of `;`?

@AntalS-Z Yuppers; I really like that post :-)

Comment: I wasn't the one who said anything about `;`; you are looking for @chi. And since the topic has been broached, my favorite monad article was [Why Do Monads Matter](https://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/why-do-monads-matter/). I know it won't be everyone's favorite, because you have to [find your own burrito](http://codetojoy.blogspot.com/2009/03/monads-are-burritos.html), but maybe it will help you along the way.

Comment: In Haskell, the "semicolon" in `a;b` is actually written `a >> b`. To account for the fact that `b` may depend on the result of `a`, we can generalize it to `a >>= b`. Most other languages implicitly work in the `IO` monad, while Haskell lets you redefine the "semicolon" `>>=` in different ways.

Comment: In the list monad `[]`, for instance, you change the "semicolon" so that the semantics of the language now is non deterministic (roughly -- it actually just return a list in a certain order). Using `Writer a` you can now collect data in a log, using `Cont r` you can do early returns. With `Maybe` or `Error a` you can have failures. With `Parser` you can express LL grammars.

Answer (score 8):

I like to think of continuations as programs with holes in them.  I think I originally gleaned this insight from [Tekmo's blog](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/12/the-continuation-monad.html).

Check out this little continuation:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont

program :: ContT () IO Char
program = ContT $ \doThing -> do
  c <- getChar
  doThing c
```

It's a program that's 'missing a piece' - namely, what to do with the `Char` retrieved from `getChar`.  We can run it by filling the missing piece with something like `putChar`; evaluating the continuation via `runContT program putChar` will get a character and then print it to stdout.

If you're comfortable with representing programs by abstract syntax trees the container analogy might be intuitive.

To make it clearer, you can build up a little AST containing a `DoThing` term that represents a hole that needs to be filled:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.Free

data ExprF a =
    GetChar (Char -> a)
  | DoThing Char a
  deriving Functor

type Expr = Free ExprF

getChar' :: Expr Char
getChar' = liftF (GetChar id)

doThing' :: Char -> Expr ()
doThing' c = liftF (DoThing c ())

program' :: Expr ()
program' = do
  c <- getChar'
  doThing' c
```

`program'` is hopefully more clearly a container; to run it we need to process the AST in a similar fashion as we would any other recursive container:

```
eval :: Expr () -> (Char -> IO ()) -> IO ()
eval prog f = iterM alg prog where
  alg (GetChar k)   = getChar >>= k
  alg (DoThing c k) = f c >> k
```

Evaluating `program'` via `eval program' putChar` is analogous to running `program` via `runContT program putChar`.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the insight and link; but I'm still more interested in how to view this monad as an aggregation. That is, for example `Reader e` is not immediately seen to be an aggregation, but when you note that a function space `e -> a` is nothing more than a power space `a ^ e`, then you note that this is just a sequence of `a` of "length" |e|. I am aiming for something as ubiquitous to assign as intuition for the continuation monad. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6):

The real key to understanding monads is to stop trying to say

> A monad is **X**

and instead start saying

> **X** is a monad

Something is a monad if it [has a certain structure and obeys certain laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)). For the purpose of programming in Haskell, something is a `Monad` if it has the right kind and types and obeys the [`Monad` laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws).

```
 return a >>= f ≡ f a
 m >>= return   ≡ m
(m >>= f) >>= g ≡ m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

Gabriel Gonzales points out that [the monad laws are "the category laws in disguise"](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/08/the-category-design-pattern.html). We can use [`>=>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-), which is defined as follow, instead of `>>=`.

```
(f >=> g) = \x -> f x >>= g
```

When we do, the monad laws become the [category laws](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory) with identity `return` and associative composition `>=>`.

```
return >=> f    ≡ f
f >=> return    ≡ f
f >=> (g >=> h) ≡ (f >=> g) >=> h
```

In your examples you are already discussing two different things for a monad to be: an aggregation that flattens and an aggregation that prunes. Instead of trying to say that monad is both of these things we'll say that both of these things are monads. To develop intuition about what things are monads, let's talk about the largest class of things that are all monads.

#### Trees with grafting

The largest class that are `Monad`s are [trees with grafting](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2010/01/monads-are-trees-with-grafting.html) and simplification. This class is so big that every `Monad` that I know of in Haskell is a tree with grafting. Each of these monads includes a `return` which constructs a tree holding the value at the leaves and a bind `>>=` which does two things. Bind replaces each leaf with a new tree, grafting the new tree onto the tree where the leaf was, and simplies the resulting tree. The examples that you mention differ in how they simplify the tree. Which simplifications are allowed are governed by the `Monad` laws.

If we have a simple tree holding values at its leaves, it is a monad.

```
data Tree a = Branch [Tree a] | Leaf a
```

Its `return` constucts a single `Leaf`. Here's `return 1`:

```
          1
```

Its bind replaces leaves with entire trees. We start with the following tree:

```
          *
         / \
        0   1
```

And bind this to `\x -> Branch [x*2, x*2 + 1]`. We replace each leaf with the newly calculated tree.

```
        __*__
       /     \
      *       *
     / \     / \
    0   1   2   3
```

For ordinary trees, the grafting step doesn't perform any simplification. After checking that these operations obey the monad laws we can say

> A tree with grafting and no simplification is a monad

#### Flatten

Lists, bags, sets, `Maybe`, and [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) flatten all the levels of the resulting tree into a single level. Everything grafted anywhere onto  the tree ends up in the same list or bag or set or `Just`. Sets also remove any duplicates from the resulting single-layer tree.

```
          *
         / \
       [0,  1]
```

If we bind this to `\x -> [x*2, x*2 + 1]` we replace each leaf with the new tree

```
        __*__
       /     \
      *       *
     / \     / \
   [0,  1] [2,  3]
```

and then flatten the intermediate layer

```
      ____*____
     /  |   |  \
   [0,  1,  2,  3]
```

We can say that

> An aggregation that flattens is a tree with grafting and simplification

And, after checking the monad laws we can say that

> An aggregation that flattens is a monad

#### Prune

`Reader e` and [pairs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html#v:Pair) like `data Pair a = Pair a a` are a little different. They can't flatten all of the results into a single layer, or at least can't do so immediately. Instead they prune branches that didn't branch the same direction as the parent.

If we start with a pair

```
          *
         / \
       <0,  1>
```

When we bind this to `\x -> <x*2, x*2 + 1>` we replace each leaf with the new tree

```
        __*__
       /     \
      *       *
     / \     / \
   <0,  1> <2,  3>
```

We prune the branches that didn't branch the same direction

```
        __*__
       /     \
      *       *
     /         \
   <0,          3>
```

And then can additionally simplify this by flattening the layers

```
          *
         / \
       <0,  3>
```

As you pointed out, `Reader e a` branches a number of directions equal to the number of possible values of `e`.

We can say that

> An aggregation that prunes and flattens is a tree with grafting and simplification

And, after checking the monad laws we can say that

> An aggregation that prunes and flattens is a monad

#### Continuations

The *continuation monad* is a tree that has a branch for each of the possible *continuations*. We will adopt the [terminology Philip JF suggested for continuations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25657590/414413). The *continuation monad* is the whole `(a -> r) -> r`. The *continuation* is the `a -> r` function passed in as the first argument

```
--                               continuation                                 
--                               |------|            
data Cont r a = Cont {runCont :: (a -> r) -> r}
--                               |-----------|
--                               continuation monad
```

The continuation monad has a number of branches equal to `|r| ^ |a|`, the number of possible values of the continuation `a -> r`. Each branch is labeled with a corresponding function. **A continuation always holds the same value in every leaf**, which we will justify in a moment. We will also be adding labels to the internal nodes of the tree, a function `r -> r`, which I'll discuss later.

We'll use the following data type to write out an example tree.

```
data Tri = A | B | C
```

Our example tree will be for `return A :: Cont Bool Tri`. The type of the values held in the tree, `Tri`, has three constructors, and the result of the contination monad, `Bool`, has two constructors. There are `2 ^ 3 = 8` possible functions `Tri -> Bool`, each of which makes up one branch of the tree.

```
                               id *
      ____________________________|____________________________
false |     a |     b |     c |  aOrB |  aOrC |  bOrC |  true |
      A       A       A       A       A       A       A       A
```

["The way to a Monad's heart is through its Kleisli arrows"](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/12/the-continuation-monad.html). [Kleisli arrows](https://wiki.haskell.org/Arrow_tutorial#Kleisli_Arrows) are the things you can pass to the second argument of `>>=`; they have the type `a -> m b`. We are going to study the Kleisli arrows of `Cont` which have the type `a -> Cont r b`, or, when we look through the `Cont` constructor

```
a -> (b -> r) -> r
```

We can break the Kleisli arrows of the contination monad `a -> (b -> r) -> r` into two parts. The first part is the function that decides what `b` to pass into the continuation `b -> r`. The only thing it has to work with is the `a` argument, so it must be one of the functions  `g :: a -> b`. The second part is the function that combines the results. It can see the argument `a` and the result of passing `g a` into the continuation. We will call this second function `r :: a -> r -> r`. All functions of type `a -> (b -> r) -> r` can be written in the form

```
a  -> (b -> r) -> r
\x -> \f       -> r x (f (g x))
```

for some `g :: a -> b` and `r :: a -> r -> r`.

Similarly, every continuation monad `(a -> r) -> r` can be written in the form

```
(a -> r) -> r
\f       -> r (f a)
```

for some `a :: a` and `r :: r -> r`. Combined these make up the justification that a continuation monad always holds the same value in every leaf.

When we bind a function `\x -> \f -> r x (f (g x))` onto a continuation monad tree we will record `g x` as the new leaves and record `(r x, g x)` as the label for the new intermediate node. The trees are really big, but we'll draw the corner of another complete example using `\x -> \f -> r x (f (g x)) :: Tri -> (Bit -> Bool) -> Bool` where `Bit` only has two constructors. The resulting continuation monad should only have `|Bool| ^ |Bit| = 4` branches, but we haven't simplified it yet.

```
                                            id *  
                _______________________________|_...
          false |                         a |
            r A *                       r A *
       _________|____________          _____|_...
bfalse |  b0 |  b1 |  btrue |   bfalse |  b0 |  
      g A   g A   g A      g A        g A   g A
```

Since every leaf holds the same value, the only differences between the paths through the tree are the functions labeling each branch. We will drop the labels from the branches and only draw a single branch. Our first example for `return a` will now be drawn as

```
        id *
           |
           A
```

And the example of binding `\x -> \f -> r x (f (g x))` onto `return A` will be drawn as

```
        id *
           |
       r A *
           |
          g A
```

Any continuation monad written in the form `\f -> r (f a)` for some `a :: a` and `r :: r -> r` will be represented by the tree

```
         r *
           |
           a
```

When bound to `\x -> \f' -> r' x (f' (g' x))`, it will be represented by the following tree (this is just grafting)

```
           r *
             |
        r' a *
             |
           g' a
```

We are going to figure out what the simplification step is from the [definition of `>>=` for `Cont`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#instance%20Monad%20(ContT%20r%20m)).

```
m >>= k = Cont $ \ c -> runCont m (\x -> runCont (k x) c)

(\f -> r (f a)) >>= (\x' -> \f' -> r' x' (f' (g' x')))
= \c -> (\f -> r (f a)) (\x -> (\x' -> \f' -> r' x' (f' (g' x'))) x c) -- by definition
= \c -> (\f -> r (f a)) (\x -> (       \f' -> r' x  (f' (g' x )))   c) -- beta reduction
= \c -> (\f -> r (f a)) (\x ->                r' x  (c  (g' x ))     ) -- beta reduction
= \c ->        r ((\x -> r' x  (c  (g' x))) a) -- beta reduction
= \c ->        r (       r' a  (c  (g' a))   ) -- beta reduction
= \c ->       (r .       r' a) (c  (g' a))     -- f (g x) = (f . g) x
= \c -> (r . r' a) (c (g' a))                  -- whitespace
```

which is in the form `\f -> r (f a)`. Our tree will be simplified to

```
    r . r' a *
             |
           g' a
```

The continuation monad is a tree whose internal nodes are labeled with functions. Its bind operation is tree grafting followed by a simplification step. The simplification step composes the functions on the internal nodes. We can say that

> The continuation monad is a tree with grafting and simplification

And, after checking the monad laws we can say that

> The continuation monad is a monad